# Regex Parsing MYSQL string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, pattern-matching

I need help with parsing **mysql 'WHERE' string** with regex to get all items into groups.
For ex. I have this string:

```
price1 < price2 && price1 > 1000 && price1!=999 && title = hello
```

So, I need to get separately columns with condition (for ex. price1 < price2) and operators && or ||

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Please  give us a complete example of table data and expected output. Otherwise, this is unanswerable and will be closed.

Comment: Would that suit? `([^&|]+)(&&|\|\|)?`.

Comment: Don't you mean `title == hello`?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder - _in SQL_, equality is tested with `=`, not `==`.  Anyway, he probably meant `title = "hello"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to *locate* `&&`.  With that, you can use `MID()` to extract the stuff before and after.

You would need a Stored Routine to loop through the string, picking up multiple pieces.

It would be better to use a 'real' language, not SQL for the task at hand.